# c++ - OpenCV - Circular switch cameras with cvCaptureFromCam

Tags: c++, opencv

My app could be executed in computer with 0 or 100 cameras connected. I need to do code to switch camera until computer have not any more camera to use. In this case, the source should be 0 again. To implement that, I have used the following code:

```
CvCapture * capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(_source);

// Try to open capture and if it fails go to first camera
if(!capture){
    _source = 0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(_source);
}
```

With this code, I want to try with one source (for example 3) and if the computer have not 3 cameras, go to the first camera (source 0). The issue is that, although source is 5, cvCaptureFromCAM always return a valid capture, with capture for the last camera used, never NULL to switch to 0 and get source from camera 0. Any idea about how implement this "circular" switch?

An option is get the count of cameras and do module operation in this range,  but as far I know OpenCV doesn't have one method to get count of available cameras.

Answer (score 0):

"Last camera used" suggests that you did not in fact release that camera. Try releasing the old camera before switching to a new camera.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The switch work properly if I switch from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2, ... The issue is not related about releasing the camera, is switching from "ncameras"(the last) to 0. Also, I am doing cvReleaseCapture when capture end.